# Recursividad en Newlisp

Tags: recursión, newlisp

Necesito invertir un número (1234-->4321) pero en lenguaje newlisp.

El código en Java es el siguiente:

```
static int invertir(int num,int multiplicador)
        {            
            int inverso=num;
            if(num!=0)
                {
                if(multiplicador==0)
                for (multiplicador = 10; (num/multiplicador)>10; multiplicador=multiplicador*10);
                inverso=((num%10)*multiplicador)+invertir((num/10) , (multiplicador/10));
                }       
            return inverso;
        }
```

Donde sus valores de entrada son el numero a invertir y un 0.
Y el código que tengo en newlisp es el siguiente:

```
(define (invertir n m)
(set 'm 10)
(set 'I n )
    (if (= m 0)(while (> (/ n m ) 10)(set ('m '(* m 10)))))
(if (!= n 0)
(;incio caso true
    set 'I (+ (*(% n 10) m)  (invertir (/ n 10)(/ m 10)))
);caso true
I ;caso false
);fin if
I
);fin define
```

Desconozco cómo retornar el valor para ir construyendo el número inverso.
Lo intenté con el número 9123 y la salida en newlisp es un 150

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Hola Gus, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. ¿Podrías aclara a qué quieres que te ayuden? Si estás pidiendo que escriban el código por ti, siento decir que desafortunadamente no funciona así el sitio. Puedes conocer más sobre como funciona esta comunidad, visitando el  [tour]. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Bienvenido. A la pregunta le falta una breve descripción de lo que has intentado, buscado, investigado. Por favor toma el [tour] y revisa [ask]

Comment: Gracias, trataré de dejarlo más claro

Comment: También deberías prestar ateción al etiquetado de la pregunta. Has cogido Java sólo porque has puesto un ejemplo de lo que quieres en otro lenguaje, pero para tu caso creo que con decir que quieres invertir los números para que se lea al revés es suficiente. Etiquetarlo como Java lleva a confusión.

Answer (score -1):

```
(define (invierte n) 
(if(> n 0) (invierte (/ n 10)
(set 'x (% n 10))
(print x)
))
)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir más información a la respuesta (p.e. detalles y descripción de lo que hace el código)? Tal y como está ahora no está muy claro cómo este código puede ayudar a resolver la pregunta